# List<dynamic> on NServiceBus Message

Tags: nservicebus

I'm using NServiceBus to power the back-end of an application with a
JavaScript client. Therefore, we have lots of cases where our commands
really want dynamic lists (object arrays in JS, List in C#). e.g.:

JSON:

```
{
    "listProperty" : [
        {
            "propertyA" : "value",
            "propertyB" : "valueB"
        },
        {
            "propertyQ" : "valueQ"
        }
    ]
}
```

C#:

```
class TheCommand : IMessage {
    public List<dynamic> ListProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Is there a way to do this with NServiceBus?

----- Experimentation Results -----

Some experimentation with the XML Serializer from NServiceBus shows that
it does not understand the dynamics:

```
<TheCommand>
<ListProperty>
<Object>
</Object>
</ListProperty>
</TheCommand>
```

They simply serialize (and deserialize) as Objects, with no properties.

(This a bit of a cross-post with the yahoo group as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With our JS clients we use a set of REST style services that handle serialization and passing messages to NSB.  We pass variable length arrays all the time.

In reference to dynamic structures all together, NSB requires a message to be formatted specifically to activate its handlers.  It may be a good idea to implement your own serializer.  You must implement `NServiceBus.Serialization.IMessageSerializer`.  Beyond that you must also be able to tell NSB to use that serializer and you may have your own custom configuration that goes along with it.  Take a look at the class `ConfigureXmlSerializer`.

I also just saw that in the 3.0 branch there is a JSON/BSON serializer implemented.  I've never used it, but it may meet your needs.

Comment: Ah, not the length, but the structure of the contained objects (type), needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Edited the answer to include more content on dynamic structures

Comment: We do have a defined structure, this particular case is for an upsert to a schemaless document database. The dynamic portion of the document is simply passed through and stored.

Comment: I'm certainly _not_trying to bypass the type-based routing NServiceBus provides, I simply need the ability for a portion of the payload to be dynamic.

Comment: I see, I think the easiest thing to do is just send a blob of JSON over to avoid any serialization overhead.

Comment: Right, but, in order for things to work correctly with RavenDB and Automapper, it'd be best if the actual message type had a dynamic property...

Comment: Since the serializer don't deal with it, I'll look for any sort of extension point on the serializer...

Comment: Sure, you can write you own serializer.  Obviously this requires the custom initialization.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the API points to provide my own serializer would you? If you want the points I think that'd be an acceptable (and valuable) answer to this question.

Comment: Updated per your request, I also noted that in 3.0 there is a JSON serializer that I stumbled upon.